# Updating old changesets - Liquibase

Tags: database-migration, liquibase

We use liquibase for source controlling the database. Initially, we started with Postgres and created the changesets with datatype of columns which are specific to Postgres.

For example, we have a changeset which creates the table with fields of type 'JSON'. Now that, we wanted to move to other database. So, when we run the changeset against the other database, it fails to create the table. I tried adding 'failOnError=false'. But, the later changesets failed because the table doesnot exist.

Could you please suggest how to refactor the old changeset to make compatible with other database as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your changesets database specific. You could try re-creating the changeset to work in the new DB, and adding the "dbms" attribute equal to the new DB to the new changeset. While adding the same attribute but with the old DB to the old changeset.